# HTML for JavaScript Visual Studio Extension fails to install in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

When installing the [HTML for JavaScript Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.HtmlForJavascript) for Visual Studio 2022 it fails with the following error: [image: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be resolved with a little effort:

1. Open the VSIX installer with a zip program.
2. Modify the `catalog.json` file inside the VSIX folder and find the entry for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor` and update it to be `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor":"[17.0,18.0)`
3. Modify the `extension.vsixmanifest` file inside the VSIX folder and update the file with the changes below:

Lines 12 through 18 updates to:

```
<Installation>
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0,18.0)" />
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" Version="[17.0, 18.0)">
    <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
  </InstallationTarget>
</Installation>
```

Line 22 updates to:

```
<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[17.0,18.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
```

4. Run the VSIX with all Visual Studio instances closed and enjoy your plugin!

[image: Successfully installed HTML for JavaScript Extension for Visual Studio 2022]